# django built in comments

Tags: python, django, frameworks, comments

I am using djangos built in comments framework presented in this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/comments/example/
And there is a sample code of how to implement a basic comment submission form
`{% render_comment_form for entry %}`

and when I use this code i get an error that my news model doesent have "add_comment" attribute. but there's no word about it in the example so I am asking how this "add_comment" shoudl work ?

> Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried add_comment in module news.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_comment'

Comment: Maybe show us your `urls.py`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an error in urls.py file in your "news" app. It seems like one of URL patterns there is referring to a non-existing "add_comment" function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added comments in urls.py?
like so:

```
url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
```

Comment: Yes, and nothing has changed : /

Comment: gimme example of how you actually added tag to render comments.